# Formatting GET request from Eve interface

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, curl, eve

I am using Eve as the REST interface on my mongodb instance.
I would like to save the output of a particular field only, rather than the entire payload.

Right now, for the following command:

```
curl -g http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/people?where={%22first_name%22:%20%22myself%22} -o "C:\\Users\xxx\Desktop\output.txt"
```

I save the output to output.txt file, and it looks like this:

```
{"_items": [{"_id": "5a5f753e24b8bd18d4d28593", "file": "BASE64STRING", _updated": "Wed, 17 Jan 2018 16:09:34 GMT", "_created": "Wed, 17 Jan 2018 16:09:34 GMT", "_etag": "f38ef69eda077456da63ce8246a1d6665413f1cb"}]}
```

Where BASE64 string is the image I retrieved from the database. 
How can I save only the BASE64 string rather than saving the entire "items,id,file" etc from the GET request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `urllib` (or `urllib2` for Python2) to get the response; `urllib` is  python's default library for accessing internet resources.
Then you can process the response content with `json`, select the "file" item, and save to file.

```
import urllib.request 
import json

url = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/people?where={"first_name": "myself"}'
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
j = json.loads(r.read().decode())
data = j['_items'][0]['file']

with open('C:\\Users\xxx\Desktop\output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the answer. That's exactly what I wanted to do.
I was trying to use a single curl command to extract the response, do you know if that is possible? Or is it perhaps a setting that needs changing on Eve's end?

Comment: I don't know how you would do that with curl. If you were on linux perhaps you could use grep / sed, but why bother?

Comment: A very good point, not sure why I didn't think about doing this in Python from the beginning. Thanks, I'll leave the question open in case anyone suggests alternative solutions.